# DeviceMotion Expo iOS13

Tags: react-native, expo, aframe, ios13

I’m working on an VR app using Expo and a-frame with a webview. Everything worked well with iOS12 but I have some problems since I updated to iOS13 and SDK35. When I start the webview, it is impossible to use the VR mode, the scene can only be moved if the user is manually swiping the screen.

After some research, I found that iOS13 requires an user gesture for using the device motion:

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4277

I looked in the Expo doc but the Permissions doesn’t seem to handle the DeviceMotion permission (and the DeviceMotion page only says we can check if it’s enabled or not). Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-gesture-handler`

You can run `expo install react-native-gesture-handler`

You can use this if you want to solve the problem of gestures. The rights to gestures appear to be missing from the document.

**Example**

```js
import { TapGestureHandler, RotationGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class ComponentName extends Component { 
  render () {
    return (
      <TapGestureHandler>
        <RotationGestureHandler>
        ...
        </RotationGestureHandler>
      </TapGestureHandler>
    );
  }
}
```

Read the [react-native-gesture-handler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/) docs for more information on the API and usage.